MilvusException Invalid Index Type When Creating Index
I was trying to create index in my Milvus collection, but I keep getting the error below, and I am confused why this is the case.
pymilvus.exceptions.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code=65535, message=invalid index type: IVF_FLAT, local mode only support FLAT HNSW AUTOINDEX: )>

Here is the code I have been executing. The script works in Milvus 2.3.15 and pymilvus 2.3.7, however, I do not get the same results in pymilvus 2.4.4 and milvus 2.4.0.
from pymilvus import (Collection, CollectionSchema, DataType, utility, FieldSchema,connections)

connections.connect(alias='default', uri='localhost', port=19530)

fields = [
        FieldSchema(name='id', dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=50, is_primary=True),
        FieldSchema(name='community_id', dtype=DataType.INT64),
        FieldSchema(name='content', dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=65535),
        FieldSchema(name='dense_embedding', dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=3072),
    ]

schema = CollectionSchema(
            fields=fields,
            description='docs schema',
            auto_id=False,
            enable_dynamic_field=True
        )
dense_index = {
            "index_type": "IVF_FLAT",
            "metric_type": "L2",
            "params": {"nlist": 500},
        }

collection = Collection(
    name='docs',
    schema=schema,
    num_shards=2,
    consistency_level='Strong'
)        
collection.create_index("dense_embedding", dense_index)


The root cause is: the connection parameter is incorrect.
connections.connect(uri='localhost', port=19530)
should be
connections.connect(host='localhost', port=19530)
uri='localhost' will launch a milvus lite, which is a local lightweight server. With the connection, all the API are redirected to the lite server, not the standalone container.

I tried running your code and I believe the cause of the error is that the connection parameter is incorrect. You have connections.connect(uri='localhost', port=19530), which should be connections.connect(host='localhost', port=19530)instead.
uri='localhost' will launch a local Milvus Lite server that does not support IVF_FLAT index. With the connection established, all your APIs will be redirected to the lite server instead the standalone you deployed.
